# Extent flip card function - Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Currently I am facing the problem that each button triggers both cards to flip. However, I am aiming for each button to flip only the appropriate card (not both of them). Is it possible to extent this `jquery` function on as many cards as I want?

I hope my problem becomes clear when looking at the code snippet.

Any hints are highly appreciated.

Regards

```css
.wrappercard {
    width: 285px; 
    height: 350px; 
    margin-top: 50px;
    margin-left: 50px;
}

.containercard {
    height: 330px;
    width: 285px; 
    -webkit-perspective: 800px;
    -moz-perspective: 800px;
    -o-perspective: 800px;
    perspective: 800px;
}

.card {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 1s;
    -moz-transition: -moz-transform 1s;
    -o-transition: -o-transform 1s;
    transition: transform 1s;
    -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
    -moz-transform-style: preserve-3d;
    -o-transform-style: preserve-3d;
    transform-style: preserve-3d;
    -webkit-transform-origin: 50% 50%;
}

.card div {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
    -moz-backface-visibility: hidden;
    -o-backface-visibility: hidden;
    backface-visibility: hidden;
}

.card.flipped {
    -webkit-transform: rotateY( 180deg );
    -moz-transform: rotateY( 180deg );
    -o-transform: rotateY( 180deg );
    transform: rotateY( 180deg );
}

/* Front Styling */ 
.card .front {
    background: white;
    box-shadow: 2px 2px 15px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8); 
    border-radius: 5px;
}

/*Back Styling*/
.card .back {
    background: white;
    box-shadow: 2px 2px 15px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8); 
    border-radius: 5px;
    -webkit-transform: rotateY( 180deg );
    -moz-transform: rotateY( 180deg );
    -o-transform: rotateY( 180deg );
    transform: rotateY( 180deg );
    overflow: hidden;
}

/*Button flip*/ 
.btnflip {
    border: none; 
    background: none;
    margin-left: 50%; 
    transform: translate(-50%); 
    width: 100%;
    margin-top: 10px;
    font-size: 14px;
    font-weight: lighter; 
    cursor: pointer;
    padding: 3px 20px 3px 20px;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 14px rgba(50, 59, 74, 0.20);
    border-radius: 4px;
    transition: 0.3s ease-in-out;
}

.btnflip:hover {
    background-color: white; 
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 14px rgba(50, 59, 74, 0.80);
    transition: 0.3s ease-in-out;
    
}

.btnflip:focus {
    outline: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="wrappercard"> 
        <section class="containercard">
            <div class="card">
                <div class="front">
                  Hello 
                </div>
                
                <div class="back">
                  Bye
                </div>
            </div>
        </section>
        <button class="btnflip" onclick="flip()">Anfragen</button>    
    </div>
        
        
    <div class="wrappercard">
        <section class="containercard">
            <div class="card">
                <div class="front">
                   Hello
                </div>
                
                <div class="back">
                   Bye
                </div>
            </div>
        </section>
        <button class="btnflip" onclick="flip()">Anfragen</button>    
    </div>
        
        <script>
            function flip() {
                $('.card').toggleClass('flipped');
            }
        </script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you add the event handler via jquery then you get `this`, which is the button clicked.

```
 <button class="btnflip">Anfragen</button>
```

then you can use relative path traversal to find the related card:

```
$(function() { 
    $(".btnflip").click(function() {
        $(this).closest(".wrappercard").find('.card').toggleClass('flipped');
    })
});
```

```js
$(function() { 
        $(".btnflip").click(function() {
            $(this).closest(".wrappercard").find('.card').toggleClass('flipped');
        })
    });
```

```css
.wrappercard {
    width: 285px; 
    height: 350px; 
    margin-top: 50px;
    margin-left: 50px;
}

.containercard {
    height: 330px;
    width: 285px; 
    -webkit-perspective: 800px;
    -moz-perspective: 800px;
    -o-perspective: 800px;
    perspective: 800px;
}

.card {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 1s;
    -moz-transition: -moz-transform 1s;
    -o-transition: -o-transform 1s;
    transition: transform 1s;
    -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
    -moz-transform-style: preserve-3d;
    -o-transform-style: preserve-3d;
    transform-style: preserve-3d;
    -webkit-transform-origin: 50% 50%;
}

.card div {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
    -moz-backface-visibility: hidden;
    -o-backface-visibility: hidden;
    backface-visibility: hidden;
}

.card.flipped {
    -webkit-transform: rotateY( 180deg );
    -moz-transform: rotateY( 180deg );
    -o-transform: rotateY( 180deg );
    transform: rotateY( 180deg );
}

/* Front Styling */ 
.card .front {
    background: white;
    box-shadow: 2px 2px 15px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8); 
    border-radius: 5px;
}

/*Back Styling*/
.card .back {
    background: white;
    box-shadow: 2px 2px 15px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8); 
    border-radius: 5px;
    -webkit-transform: rotateY( 180deg );
    -moz-transform: rotateY( 180deg );
    -o-transform: rotateY( 180deg );
    transform: rotateY( 180deg );
    overflow: hidden;
}

/*Button flip*/ 
.btnflip {
    border: none; 
    background: none;
    margin-left: 50%; 
    transform: translate(-50%); 
    width: 100%;
    margin-top: 10px;
    font-size: 14px;
    font-weight: lighter; 
    cursor: pointer;
    padding: 3px 20px 3px 20px;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 14px rgba(50, 59, 74, 0.20);
    border-radius: 4px;
    transition: 0.3s ease-in-out;
}

.btnflip:hover {
    background-color: white; 
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 14px rgba(50, 59, 74, 0.80);
    transition: 0.3s ease-in-out;
    
}

.btnflip:focus {
    outline: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="wrappercard"> 
        <section class="containercard">
            <div class="card">
                <div class="front">
                  Hello 
                </div>
                
                <div class="back">
                  Bye
                </div>
            </div>
        </section>
        <button class="btnflip">Anfragen</button>    
    </div>
        
    <div class="wrappercard">
        <section class="containercard">
            <div class="card">
                <div class="front">
                   Hello
                </div>
                
                <div class="back">
                   Bye
                </div>
            </div>
        </section> 
        <button class="btnflip">Anfragen</button>    
    </div>
```